# Mediawiki - permissions so that anonymous can createpage, but only users can edit

Tags: mediawiki

The second part of this question is easy. This in LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit'] = true;
```

dictates that only users can edit.

My issue is that for createpage permissions to be set the user or group has to also have edit permissions.

I want anonymous users to be able to make submissions (via Semantic Forms) but only users to be able to edit them.

Any help appreciated,
Carl.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's possible with the current permissions system in MediaWiki.  By design,  there's very little a user without the `edit` permission can do; that permission controls the right to modify the wiki content in any way.  I guess you could file a feature request for a separate `editexisting` permission to specifically forbid only the editing of existing pages.

Actually, I suppose you could implement such a permission yourself with a [`userCan` hook](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/userCan), something like this:

```php
function checkEditExisting( &$title, &$user, $action, &$result ) {
    if ( $action != 'edit' ) return true;
    if ( !$title->exists() ) return true;
    if ( $user->isAllowed('editexisting') ) return true;
    return $result = false;  // page exists, no permission -> disallow edit
}
$wgHooks['userCan'][] = 'checkEditExisting';

$wgGroupPermissions['*']['editexisting'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['editexisting'] = true;
```

Note that I haven't tested the code above at all, but it's simple enough that, with some luck, it might just work.